# smtpd_recipient_restrictions: Some RBLs working, but SBL isn't

Tags: centos, email, postfix, spam, spam-filter

I'm trying to set up postfix so that it uses blocklists to block spam.
This is my restriction setting in main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,check_policy_service unix:private/spfpolicy
```

I tested the restriction by sending an email to the crynwr.com service which replies with an email from a blocked IP.

maillog showed this when it delivered:

```
Aug 23 12:06:27 srv2 postfix/smtpd[23321]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ns1.crynwr.com[192.203.178.14]: 454 4.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [192.203.178.14] blocked using b.barracudacentral.org; Client host blocked using Barracuda Reputation, see http://www.barracudanetworks.com/reputation/?r=1&ip=192.203.178.14; from=<nelson-expn@crynwr.com> to=<MYEMAILADDRESS(REDACTED)> proto=SMTP helo=<pdam.crynwr.com>
```

So it shows that something gets rejected by postfix, but the email arrives from another IP and gets delivered as it showed up in my inbox: [Picture of the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeBE4.png)

I'm really lost and don't even know where to start looking so I'll update this with more info if need.

I am running Centos 6.8 with the Centos Web Panel.

EDIT: Updated to fit discovery that Barracuda blocklist was working, but zen.spamhaus.org wasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the default DNS being used was the Google DNS, which did not agree with Spamhaus' services. The issue was resolved by switching to OpenDNS. This was done by editing /etc/resolv.conf
and replace

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

with

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

then restarting the server.